# Eclipse (ADT) issue with C++ smart pointers

Tags: eclipse, c++11, adt, smart-pointers

I am using "Android Developer Tools - Build: v22.0.5-757759"

When I try to use 'smart pointers' e.g. std::unique_ptr<>, eclipse editors do not recognize this as valid class. I get the error 'Symbol unique_ptr can not be resolved'. But it compiles without any issue and also runs good.

I tried so many things explained in other posts on this site, but was not able to get it to work. Looks like many got this resolved, can someone give me clear instructions, how to resolve this issue using ADT.

My requirements are

Android App development 
Converted project as C++ project

Thanks

MB

Comment: Eclipse parser is not so good. It simply can not parse smart pointers because of complexity. Hopefully they improve it in the future